# Find the essential spectrum of an operator in $L_p(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the operator $$(Ax)(t) = x(t-a), a \in \mathbb{R}$$ I'm trying to find essential spectrum of this operator in spaces $L_p[0, 1], p \in [1, \infty]$. However, I'm unable to find essential spectrum, can somebody help me? Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand this operator, if $a=1/2$, $(Ax)(1/4)$? In other words, either we should look at this operator on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ or describe what the shifts look like for values such as these.

Comment: I see now that the question in the body (which is nonsense) doesn’t match the question in the title, which is sensible. You should edit these to match

Comment: @operatorerror $L_p$ is the same space as $L^p$ just different labels

Comment: Yes obviously, but $L_p[0,1]$ is not the same thing as $L_p(\mathbb{R})$! This is why the body of your question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will denote the left shift operator as $A_{-a}$, and the right shift operator as $A_a$. It's easy to see that $\|A_{-a}\|=\|A_{a}\|=1$, moreover, these operators are mutually inverse. Since they are both bounded, their spectrums are mutually inverse, so they can only lie on the unit circle. It follows from the general theory that the essential spectrum is non-empty, therefore, it also lies on the unit circle. Choose $\lambda_0=e^{i\varphi_0}$ and introduce the isometric operator $Ux=e^{-\frac{i\varphi_0t}{a}}x(t)$. Then $$(A_{-a}-\lambda_0I)Ux=e^{-\frac{i\varphi_0(t-a)}{a}}x(t-a)-e^{i\varphi_0}e^{-\frac{i\varphi_0t}{a}}x(t)=e^{i\varphi_0}e^{-\frac{i\varphi_0t}{a}}(A_{-a}-I)x=V(A_{-a}-I)x,$$
where $Vx=e^{i\varphi_0}e^{-\frac{i\varphi_0t}{a}}x(t)$ is an isometric operator. Thus, the operators $A_{-a}-\lambda_0I$ and $A_{-a}-I$ are weakly equivalent (i.e. $AU=VB$ with isometric isimorphisms $U$ and $V$). This means that $\lambda_0$ will be a point of spectrum of $A_{-a}$, up to classification, if and only if its spectrum point is $1$. Thus, firstly, the entire spectrum of the operator coincides with the unit circle, and, secondly, the entire spectrum will be essential.